# Distribution of a sum of normal random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be independently distributed variables where $X_k \sim N(k\mu, 1)$ for $k = 1, 2, ..., n$ and $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ unknown.

I calculated that the ML estimator for $\mu$ is equal to
$$\hat{\mu}_{ML}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k x_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n k^2}.$$
My question is, what is the distribution of $\hat{\mu}_{ML}$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: little known fact: sum of Gaussian is Gaussian. Can you compute mean and variance now?

Comment: For those interested, this is a property shared by [stable distributions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator (being a sum of Gaussian) is distributed $$
\mathcal N(\sum k^2\mu_k,\sum k^2)
$$while the denominator is simplified as $$
\sum^n_{k=1}k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=c
$$So the distribution you need is$$
\mathcal N(\frac{1}{c}\sum k^2\mu_k,\frac{1}{c^2}\sum k^2)
$$

Comment: I see, I don't why I was overthinking it too much. Thank you very much!

Comment: In $\hat \mu=\frac{1}{nk^2}\sum_k^nkx_k$, how did $k$ get outside the summation?

Comment: My apologies, I must have visually mistaken the denominator as a summation unrelated to $k$

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is only partially correct. Your estimator is indeed normally distributed, with the mean exactly $\mu$ (so your estimator is unbiased) and the variance
$$
\left(\frac1{\sum_{k=1}^n k^2}\right)^2\times\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\cdot 1=\frac1{\sum_{k=1}^n k^2}.
$$